# ASP.Net MVC ParitalView and Javascript / jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to have a PartialView execute the jQuery ready function on load of the PartialView. I do this all of the time in a regular View.

For example, I want to do something like this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MainConfig.Models.ProfileAddress>" %>

<script type="text/javascript">

     $(function () {        

        alert('I am in ProfileAddress PartialView');
     }

</script>

Partial View Html Code Here
```

Maybe I have to do something on the server side.

Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Your code will work as long as the partial view is rendered.

Comment: I am sorry, I should of asked the question differently.  The right question is, what is wrong with the code in the original post. I tried this and it is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I found my problem. I was missing a parentheses. Thanks for confirming this would work. It caused me to review the code again. Here is the correct code: <%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MainConfig.Models.ProfileAddress>" %> <script type="text/javascript"> $(function () { alert("I am in ProfileAddress PartialView"); }) </script>